# how to solve this type error like UCrop.REQUEST_CROP == 69

Tags: android

```
if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
    final Uri resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(imageReturnedIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "result" + resultUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("camerauriresult", "" + resultUri);
}
```

Comment: can you share the logcat?